# Php get a value from url using a class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here is the div code on different domains, i want to display total on my homepage. I try to use the file_get_html but it displays all the div content, but i want to save the number within the `<dd></dd>` in a variables and add them and display them on my page. 
here is the div code

```
<div class="stats">
    <dl class="statscount">
        <dt>total:</dt>
        <dd>5,299</dd>
    </dl>    
    20000
</div>
```

and here is my current code.

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = file_get_html('http://www.targetdomain.com');
$result = $html->find('dl[class=statscount]', 0);  //Output: THESE
$result = str_replace(",", "", $result);
echo $result;
?>
```

but there is small problem i don't need to fetch all the data in the class, i just need  data for `<dd></dd>` tag within the class, Can you please tell me how to achieve this. basically i want to fetch the number within the `<dd>5,299</dd>` and add all the numbers from different pages and display the total on my website. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use [XPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) for this, this way you won't need simple_html_dom because DOM and XPath is part of the PHP5 core:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<div class="stats">
  <dl class="statscount">
    <dt>total posts:</dt>
    <dd>5,299</dd>
  </dl>
  20000
</div>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
$value = $selector
    ->query('//dl[@class="statscount"]/dd/text()')
    ->item(0)
    ->nodeValue;

var_dump($value); // Output: string(5) "5,299"
```

You can test the code [here](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/12u-ser)

Comment: The div code page is on different domain where we are fetching the data, will this code work with that. Thanks

Comment: Then you'll have to retrieve the content using `$html = file_get_contents('http://server.com/page.html');`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a regex

```
preg_match('/<dd>[^>]*(.*)<\/dd>/', $htmlcode, $matches);
$result = $matches;
```

Comment: Using a regex to extract information from a DOMDocument isn't a good idea in most cases. It tends to get messy in real world examples.